# Javascript: How to iterate only a certain part of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a javascript object that looks like this

```
const columns = {
    firstLabel: 'Hello',
    secondLabel: 'world',
    thirdLabel: 'I',
    fourthLabel: 'Am',
    fifthLabel: 'Paul',
};
```

I am trying to only get the values of the last three `I, Am, Paul`. I am doing something like this but this clearly doesn't work as this will return everything. Is this possible to do with an object?

```
 for(const prop in columns) {
      if(Object.keys(columns).length > 2){
        console.log(`${columns[prop]}`);
      }
 }
```

Expected output is just:

I

Am

Here

Comment: `Object.values(columns).slice(-3)`

Comment: The order of keys in an object is not guaranteed and you shouldn't code for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with,

```
const lastThree = Object.values(columns).slice(-3);
console.log(lastThree);
```

The answer is:

```
[ 'I', 'Am', 'Paul' ]
```